# Check if HashSet of objects contains two objects with same field

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have this class:

```
class Person {
    string name;
}
```

Suppose I have a `HashSet<Person> people` with some objects in.

It is guaranteed that there will be at most 2 objects in `people` that have the same name.

Is there a way to find a pair of people with the same name inside `people` with Linq of another short way?

I could obviously run 2 fors, but I guess there may be a oneliner for that?

Comment: maybe try to override the Equals? eg `public override bool Equals(object obj)`

Comment: Use GroupBy to group the objects by a property, then use Where on the resulting grouping to find groups with 2 or more objects.

Comment: Either add an `Equals` method to your `Person` class or use the `HashSet` constructor taking an `IEqualityComparer<T>` instance and create a PersonNameEqualityComparer class implementing this interface.